# Find Capital words in java

Tags: java

How can I extract two or more words that separated by white space which begin with capital letter and save them as a single token in java ?

Comment: You could remove the space with `string.replace(" ","");` if that's what you mean.

Comment: I do not want to remove space , I have a text and just to extract two or more words which start with capital letters for exaple:

Comment: I am at New South Welse at the moment. out put is: New South Welse

Comment: It won't remove space from original `String` but will return new String with spaces removed

Comment: `"I am at New South Welse at the moment"` why `I` is not returned but only `New`, `South` and `Welse`? Is it because it is not after space or because you don't consider one letter words as words?

Comment: Use a regular expression to identify consequent capitalized words if you have no better option.

Comment: Firstly input text file is random and as I said two or more words which starts with capital should be considered as a token not a word .Are there any pattern to extract them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regexp to find several words within the sentence, space is used as the split character, you can add others.

```
((?<=\s)[A-Z][\w]*\s)+[A-Z][\w]*(?=\s)
```

Comment: If words can contain numbers this expression can be little improved by using `\\w` instead of `[A-Za-z]` :)

Comment: Agree) I have updated the answer.

Comment: Actually `\\w` is class so you don't need to put it in `[]` (just like with `\\s` in your regex)

Comment: it give me illegal escape charecter

Comment: @user1608657 try replacing \ with \\

Comment: Can you give me complete regex to test it ,

Comment: @user1608657 I would try with something like this `Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)[A-Z]\\w*(\\s+[A-Z]\\w*)+(?=$|\\s)");`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following as a starting point:

```
String input = "This is a sentence with two Words with capital letters";
String[] words = input.split(" ");

for(String word : words)
{
    if(word.length() > 0 && Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0)))
    {
        System.out.println("Upper case: " + word);
    }
    else
    {
        // doesn't have upper case at beginning
    }
}
```

The output will be:

> Upper case: This
>
> Upper case: Words

Comment: @HarmeetSingh Whoops, typo. Thanks.

Comment: Could also replace `word.length() > 0` with `!word.isEmpty()` for extra brevity. Although that's a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex which will match any word starting with a uppercase letter: `\b([A-Z]\w*?)\b`.

This slightly modified version will match just sequences > 2: `(\b[A-Z]\w*\b(?: (?![^A-Z]))?){2,}`.

I think with some little effort both regexs could become much smaller. But this will give you some starting point.

---

Try them at: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Comment: +1 for regex - best way to go

Comment: But I want to extract only two or more words which start with capital letter and ignore one words. for example: I am at New South Welse . He is not with me . Alex is at United Nation not Melbourne. output should be: 1:New South Welse 2: United Nation NOT I, He and of course Melbourne

Comment: @user1608657 Why should it ignore "I", but not "He" ?? Do you want to ignore words of length 1?

Comment: @Baz `I` and `He` are not part of token that contains at least two words which start with capital and are separated with white spaces.

Comment: @Pshemo Ah, I see now... But the OP should really try to improve his question.

Comment: @Baz True, it is not so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would solve your prob.

1.Using String function

```
String word = "this is my content ";
        String[] splitWord;
        String capWord = "";
        splitWord = word.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitWord.length; i++) {
           capWord = splitWord[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + splitWord[i].substring(1) + " ";
    System.out.println(capWord);
        }
```

2.Using WordUtils API

```
   String text="use this    text";
    String text1="use this TEXT";

    String word = WordUtils.capitalize(text);
    System.out.println(word);

    word = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(text1);
    System.out.println(word);
```

Comment: `splitWord[i].substring(0, 1)` could create an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if there are two consecutive spaces somewhere in the sentence.

Comment: note:above answer executes for single space between words in the   sentence

Comment: It would, if you replace `wordCapital` with `capWord`, since `wordCapital` is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions might be a good bet.

To match any series of two or more words starting with a capital letter, then you'll need to use a [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String passage = "I am at New South Welse at the moment";
        Pattern twoOrMoreWordsPattern= Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]+ +){2,}");
        Matcher twoOrMoreWordsMatcher = twoOrMoreWordsPattern.matcher(passage);
        while (twoOrMoreWordsMatcher.find()){
            for(int i = 0; i < twoOrMoreWordsMatcher.groupCount(); i++){
                System.out.print(twoOrMoreWordsMatcher.group(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

That will hopefully work and do what you want, and if it doesn't then it's close to what you want...

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\w* +([\w]+ +)+");` illegal escape character

Comment: `passage.split("\.");` illegal escape character

Comment: I mentioned that i hadn't checked it, and that it would be fairly easy to alter once you did put it through the JDE...

Comment: @will That might be true, but you should always try to post code that actually compiles and works...

Comment: i altered, but no valid output

Comment: here is output of your code `Some long body of 
With full stops between the `

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I altered it, and now it compiles, and the output it gives me is `Capital Letters` - which i believe is correct. If you altered it just by removing the `\ ` then it would not work, as it would have been looking for a `w` rather than any `word` character. If i put in the `I am at New South Welse at the moment` input, then it gives `New South Welse`.

Comment: this is my first time that I upload a question and I am not very good at java and get a lot answer please let me know which one is the best

Comment: @will where is `I` in output as `String` is `I am at New South Welse at the moment`

Comment: @HarmeetSingh it isn't, since it's not part of a string of 2 or more capitalised words